# $stateProvider params null with ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I can't retrieve parameters passed from ui-router in Ionic.
Parameters passed into the Controller are undefined
This is my state code:

```
.state('app.dayliston', { 
       cache: false,
       url: '/myurl', 
       views: { 
         'mainContent': { 
           templateUrl: 'calendar/daylist.html', 
           controller: 'MyCtrl',
             params : { 'mode':'online'}
         } 
       } 
     })
```

and here is My Controller code:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$state,  $stateParams,CalendarFactory,FBFactory, $ionicHistory,$ionicScrollDelegate,$ionicModal,$ionicPopup, $timeout) { 

         console.log('MyCtrl')
         console.log('mode'+$stateParams.mode) // mode is undefined

        .... 

})
```

I'm using 1.6.1. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in your code, you dont need to use $stateParams because you don't get the "mode" parameter from the URL.

I think attached `data` in state will be a better choice ([Docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects)):

```
.state('app.dayliston', { 
   cache: false,
   url: '/myurl', 
   data:{ 
     mode: 'online'
   },
   views: { 
     'mainContent': { 
       templateUrl: 'calendar/daylist.html', 
       controller: 'MyCtrl'
     } 
   } 
 })
```

Then you can get the data stored in state like this:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, CalendarFactory, FBFactory, $ionicHistory, $ionicScrollDelegate, $ionicModal, $ionicPopup, $timeout) { 
     console.log('MyCtrl')
     console.log('mode'+$state.current.data.mode) // "online"
})
```

Comment: you drove me to the right direction. I had just to move data  out of views

Answer (score 0):

MyCtrl is the actual name of your controller. It's not a parameter that's passed to the controller per se.

Comment: Yes it is the actual name. console.log('MyCtrl') is just a print on the screen

Comment: Where is .mode defined/set for $stateParams? The $stateParams object exists (so it's being injected properly), but the mode property is not present.

Comment: But where should I put the mode property? I thought it would be  enough to pass it in params like this: params : { 'mode':'online'}

Comment: I don't know enough about your application's structure, but these references are in the constructor of your controller. It looks like this might just be an order of execution issue. Are you perhaps loading the js for your controllers before you configure your routes?

Comment: no the order is fine. The controllers are loaded last.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the `$stateParams` incorrectly

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service

The should be on the url or you can pass data in using the `resolve` map on the state.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

also passing in custom data might be a better approach? Hard to tell from the code sample you provided

Answer (score 0):

Route:

```
.state('app.dayliston', { 
  cache: false,
  url: '/myurl/:mode', 
  views: { 
    'mainContent': { 
      templateUrl: 'calendar/daylist.html', 
      controller: 'MyCtrl'
    } 
  } 
})
```

[Check URL Routing Query Parameters doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters)

Link from view:

```
<a ui-sref="app.dayliston({mode: 'online'});">Go to dayliston</a>
```

Go to state/route from controller:

```
$state.go('app.dayliston', {mode: 'online'});
```